# slow git performance

Tags: linux, git, nfs, hdparm

I have an older machine with a git repository on it that I use to keep synchronized with svn.  I've noticed that with running basic commands like git status, it is ridiculously slow.  I was initially use SSHFS to access the repository remotely, but have changed to NFSv4, and now have even run those commands locally to find it is really slow.

I keep the repository on one machine for other reasons, so it will need to stay on the network.

I ran hdparm to try and squeeze some performance out of the disks:
hdparm -d 1 -A 1 -m 16 -u 1 -a 64 /dev/sda

(the -m flag was ignored due to safety)

Now, prior to me moving the source code to that machine, I had it on a network share where I mounted the encrypted file locally.  Even though that was on the network, I saw really good performance, almost comparable to having the workspace locally.  Before I switch back to the original approach, I was wondering what would be causing git to perform so slowly?  Is it as simple as poor drive performance?

Comment: It's probably the shared filesystem.  Take a look at [Slow Git operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669882/slow-git-operations).